"Personal Notes" in LearnR Tutorial Disappeared
I see that my progress in some tutorials have been saved, but some of them have been lost. I always save everything before quitting Rstudio, so the ones saved and/or lost are quite random. Most importantly, I have lost all my personal notes (under the "Personal Notes" section in the menu on the left) in LearnR.
1- Would you know why this could have been?
2- Is there a way to bring back personal notes (and the progress)?
I tried to search for the History on Rstudio, but it seems like the history section is only for the current session.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
